# How do you prove a subgroup is a normal subgroup of a group?

Tags: group-theory

I have a group 
$G=\{f_{a,b}\mid \text{$a,b\in\mathbb R$ and $a\ne 0$}\}$
under composition of maps, where $f_{a,b}=ax+b$.
I've proven that it is a group and then I have proved that 
$$G_1=\{f_{a,0}\mid \text{$a\in \mathbb R$ and $a \ne 0$}\}$$
and
$$G_2=(f_{1,b} \mid b\in\mathbb R\}$$
are both subgroups of $G$.

How do I show whether these subgroups are normal (or not) subgroups of $G$?

I know that a subgroup is normal if for all $g$ in $G$, $gNg^{−1} \subseteq N$. But just can't seem to get to grips with this

Comment: What do you mean by "a does not contain 0"? You stated a is a real number.

Comment: A is any real number except for 0. i.e.  a in R \{0}

Comment: If that's what you mean, then say that!

Comment: I formatted and corrected your question based on what you wrote. Please ensure that I have done so correctly.

Comment: Thanks that's a lot better.

Answer (score 3):

For $G_2$: Let's make it clear. We have $$G_2=\{x+b\mid b\in\mathbb R\}$$ and $(a'x+b')^{-1}=\left(\frac{x}{a'}-\frac{b'}{a'}\right)$. So $$(a'x+b')^{-1}(x+b)(a'x+b')=a'\left(\frac{x}{a'}-\frac{b'}{a'}\right)+a'b+b'\in G_2$$ For $G_1$, it is enough to assume $g=(x+1),~~a\neq 0$ to see that $$( x+1)^{-1}(ax)( x+1)=ax+a-1\notin G_2$$

Answer (score 2):

$G_2$ is normal if $f_{p,q}\circ f_{1,b} \circ f^{-1}_{p,q} \in G_2$

The inverse function to $f(x)=mx+b$ is $f^{-1}(x) = \frac{1}{m}x-\frac{b}{m}$

Computing the above composition gives

$f_{p,q}\circ f_{1,b} \circ f^{-1}_{p,q} = f_{p,q}\circ f_{1,b} \circ (\frac{1}{p}x-\frac{q}{p})$

$ = f_{p,q}\circ (\frac{1}{p}x-\frac{q}{p}+b)$

$ = x+pb = f_{1,pb}\in G_2$.

So $G_2$ is normal.

A similar calculation will show you $G_1$ is not.

Comment: Thanks, it's very clear now.